# Why sometimes a very long delay in calling Web API Method

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, tcp

**Details**: I'm running a VS. WebApi application on an Azure Cloud service. I'm running in a dev environment with debugging on (not sure if that matters). When I execute the web method below, using fiddler, most times the response is very fast - in the order of 200ms complete transaction time. However, on occasion the response is above 1-2 seconds. I'm trying to understand why. For troubleshooting, I'm using both the fiddler diagnostic results as well as a custom header that I place in the response that gives me some time information (X-diagnostics)

**Question(s)** : Given the fiddler response below juxtaposed with my custom diagnostics, and given once again that most times my responses are very fast;

1. Why is there a TCP/IP connect of more than 1000ms?
2. Why is there such a delay between fiddler's begin request and the entry to the method (I log start as soon as I enter the method)
3. Why is there such a delay between the method exit and fiddler's begin response.
4. Why would this happen only on occasion
5. Is there anything I can do to prevent it?

---

**Web Method**

```
    [Route("api/devicereports")]
    [Route("api/v0/devicereports")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostStatusReport([FromBody] object report, bool includeDiagnostics = false)
```

**Fiddler Response**

```
ClientConnected:      07:18:26.917
ClientBeginRequest:   07:18:26.918
GotRequestHeaders:    07:18:26.918
ClientDoneRequest:    07:18:26.918
Determine Gateway:    0ms
DNS Lookup:           0ms
TCP/IP Connect:       1015ms
HTTPS Handshake:      0ms
ServerConnected:      07:18:27.933
FiddlerBeginRequest:  07:18:27.933
ServerGotRequest:     07:18:27.933
ServerBeginResponse:  07:18:30.558
GotResponseHeaders:   07:18:30.558
ServerDoneResponse:   07:18:30.558
ClientBeginResponse:  07:18:30.558
ClientDoneResponse:   07:18:30.558

**Overall Elapsed:  0:00:03.640**
```

**My Custom Diagnostics**

```
X-Diagnostics: Start=14:18:29.885 && Finish=14:18:30.025 && Time(ms)=140  && Leave=14:18:30.025
```

**Analysis**

```
FIDDLER: RequestBegin;  27.933
CODE   : Start;         29.885
CODE   : Finish;        30.025
FIDDLER: BeginResponse; 30.558
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first request takes a little longer. The first slow response is related to the JIT compilation of the service assemblies and also, 
the IIS application pool is shut down after 30 minutes of inactivity.

After that, you'll get responses quicker.

A few things you can do:

*1- Enable always on in your webapp;*

**It's not applied since you're using Cloud Service.**

*1.1 - Disable idle timeout (through web.config file);*

**Here's how you can achieve that programatically: http://wp.sjkp.dk/windows-azure-websites-and-cloud-services-slow-on-first-request/**

*2- Call your webapi after every X minutes to avoid idle timeout;*

**You can write a worker role that call your webapi every X minutes.**

*3- Host your webapi in a self host mode (owin in a Worker Role)*

**Here's a link from Asp.Net Official Web Site: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role**

Comment: 1. I'm running a cloud service, I only see that option for WebApps, 2. The api is active while I'm doing my tests - with calls every few seconds

Comment: As you're running a cloud service, I suppose that you're using Web Role. In the end, is hosted on IIS too.